# Duke deduplication engine: can't find exact records

Tags: java, duplicates, record-linkage, duke

I'm trying to create a configuration and processor for Duke to find exact matches in a record list. I created an ExactMatchComparator based processor but the function does not return exact matches.
Here's here's the setup of the processor, configuration and listeners:

```
public void setup() {
  //setup
  List<Property> exactMatchProperties = new ArrayList<Property>();

  exactListener = new TestUtils.TestListener();

  ExactComparator exactComparator = new ExactComparator();

  //create properties (columns), with name, comparator, and high-low thresholds. ID property has no comparator or propabilities.

  exactMatchProperties.add(new PropertyImpl("ID"));
  exactMatchProperties.add(new PropertyImpl("NAME", exactComparator, 0.0, 1.0));
  exactMatchProperties.add(new PropertyImpl("EMAIL", exactComparator, 0.0, 1.0));

  //create new configuration implementation
  exactMatchConfig = new ConfigurationImpl();

  //add properties to config
  exactMatchConfig.setProperties(exactMatchProperties);
  exactMatchConfig.setThreshold(1.0);
  exactMatchConfig.setMaybeThreshold(0.0);

  //initialize the processor and add match listener
  exactMatchProcessor = new Processor(exactMatchConfig, true);
  exactMatchProcessor.addMatchListener(exactListener);
  }
```

And here's my function to test:

```
 public void testExactMatch() {
  Collection<Record> records = new ArrayList<Record>();
  Record rec1 = TestUtils.makeRecord(new String[] { "ID", "1", "NAME", "Jon", "EMAIL", "jon@doe.com" });
  Record rec2 = TestUtils.makeRecord(new String[] { "ID", "1", "NAME", "Jon", "EMAIL", "jon@doe.com" });

  records.add(rec1);
  records.add(rec2);

  exactMatchProcessor.deduplicate(records);
  System.out.println(exactListener.getMatches().size());
}
```

I'm using the API, and I've read the question on SO mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32991390/duke-deduplication-engine-exact-same-record-not-matched), but that questions refers to XML, while I'm doing the tests in Java.

Shouldn't the getMatches not be empty? How can I get a list of duplicates found, or the opposite (list of unique records, without duplicates)?
Thanks